# How do I properly use escape javascript for <%= link_to %>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a js.erb file with the following code but I can't seem to properly escape the javascript for the link_to helper method.  I think it has something to do with the quotation marks around Edit.

```
$('#microposts').prepend('<div class="micropost"><h3>' +  "<%= j @user.email %>" + '</h3>    <h3>Posted ' + "<%= j time_ago_in_words(@micropost.created_at) %>" + ' ago</h3><p>' +  "<%= j     @micropost.content %>" + '</p><p>' + "<%= j link_to "Edit",      edit_user_micropost_path(@micropost) %>" '</p></div>');
$('#new_micropost')[0].reset();
$('#micropost_count').html('<%= Micropost.count %>');
```

On a side note, how would I animate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible this isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, but I would humbly suggest that this isn't the right approach and the difficulty of escaping this properly is just a symptom of the approach being too complex.

I know what you're doing here might actually be par for the course (according to some Rails developers), but I see this as a inefficient, and worse, too complex (and therefore difficult to maintain).  Presumably some AJAX call has been made and received this dynamically generated response containing an imperative (commands to DO something; in this case, commands to modify the DOM) implemented in JavaScript.  Why not have one static chunk of JavaScript loaded when the page initially loads that knows how to take a small snippet of DATA and render it appropriately?

What you'd then do is return JSON instead of an imperative chunk of script.  Your static JavaScript method would modify the DOM by:

1. Copying a hidden snippet of easy-to-maintain HTML that's embedded on that page.
2. Doing a find/replace on the copy to "fill in the blanks" with data from the JSON structure you got from the AJAX call.
3. Prepend the collection with the new snippet of HTML.

Think this would be more straightforward with much easier maintenance.

Comment: And as for animating it.  Have a look at jQuery or your JS toolkit of choice.  Think Rails prefers JQuery these days.  You should easily find a method for animating the prepend operation.

Comment: +1. Returning JS code from Rails views is plainly unmaintainable, just return JSON that the JS in the client knows what to do with it. Fortunately I think that's the orthodox Rails view now, the times of RJS are over.

Comment: Ya.  Never cared for RJS.  Just always felt too complex.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the explanation.  I've been reading up on JSON but couldn't find a good guide to using JSON/Rails to AJAXify a form submission.  Could you explain the steps you listed in detail?  I would definitely appreciate it!

Comment: My Rails is a bit too rusty to be of help in this regard.  But if you look around, you should quite easily find examples of what I've described.  Keywords to look for would be "rails, json, views."  As for the JavaScript that makes the call and processess the JSON results, look for "jquery, ajax, json."